# Rewriting GADT code in terms of standard Haskell?

Tags: haskell, gadt

I was trying to understand the Article *[The Operational Monad Tutorial](https://apfelmus.nfshost.com/articles/operational-monad.html)* by Heinrich Apfelmus, where he uses [GADTs](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT) a lot. As a mental exercise, I tried to rewrite his code-examples so they no longer use GADTs. I couldn't do it, and now I am usure whether this is because of my limited skills, or if there is a fundamental issue.

On [r/haskell](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/md7e8/gadts_question/) Edward Kmett states that "*You can always transform a GADT into a finally [sic] tagless representation through a class if you have Rank N types.*"

But what if I don't want to use Rank N types either? I suppose, I'd have to sacrifice *something*, but I should still be able to do it.

So, if I'm willing to sacrifice some type safety, use phantom types, typeclasses and whatnot, can I then write an *eval* function for expressions (somewhat) like the ones below, without using `LANGUAGE` extensions?

```
                           -- using GADTs :
data Expr = I Int  |       -- Int  -> Expr Int
            B Bool |       -- Bool -> Expr Bool
            Add Expr Expr  -- Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
            Eq  Expr Expr  -- Expr 1   -> Expr a   -> Expr Bool
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without GADTs, you don't know whether `Expr` is well-typed, so you can only implement an `eval` which possibly throws errors.

```
eval :: Expr -> Maybe (Either Int Bool)
eval (I n) = pure (Left n)
eval (B b) = pure (Right b)
eval (Add e1 e2) = do
  x1 <- eval e1
  x2 <- eval e2
  case (x1, x2) of
    (Left n1, Left n2) -> pure (Left (n1 + n2))
    _                  -> Nothing
eval (Eq e1 e2) = do
  x1 <- eval e1
  x2 <- eval e2
  case (x1, x2) of
    (Left  n1, Left n2)  -> pure (Right (n1 == n2))
    (Right b1, Right b2) -> pure (Right (b1 == b2))
    _                    -> Nothing
```

Answer (score 5):

Without GADTs we need a `Value` sum type, encompassing all possible results. We also need to make our evaluation function partial or return something like a `Maybe Value`.

```
data Value = VI Int | VB Bool

eval :: Expr -> Value
eval (I i) = VI i
eval (B b) = VB b
eval (Add e1 e2) = case (eval e1, eval e2) of
   (VI i1, VI i2) -> VI (i1+i2)
   _              -> error "runtime type error"
...
```